# pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex, xelatex

I have just upgraded my Macbook Pro OS to El Capitan (v10.11.4).

My attempt to export a Markdown file (created using Sublime Text 2, v2.0.2, build 2221) to pdf using pandoc is now failing, and I receive the following error:

```
pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output
```

My output command is as follows:

```
pandoc doc1.md -o doc1.pdf --toc -V geometry:margin=1in --variable fontsize=10pt --variable fontfamily=utopia --variable linkcolor=blue --latex-engine=xelatex -f markdown-implicit_figures -s
```

Above command worked like a charm prior to installing El Capitan.

FYI - in searching for questions here I have not found one that gives a suitable answer.

Comment: do you have latex installed and in your path?

Comment: On Linux I solved [installing the huge texlive-xetex package](https://askubuntu.com/a/924637/349837).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El Capitan's security features disable and remove the old symlink `/usr/texbin`. If you have MacTeX 2015, they should've been installed in `/Library/TeX/texbin` as well. You'll have to update the `PATH` your using to launch pandoc to include that folder.  If you have a pre-2015 distribution of MacTeX, there are instructions [here](https://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

For my case, add one line into `~/.bashrc` solved the error:

```
export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH
```

Of course, the environment variable should be activated in the current term:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

then run: `$ make`

the error disappears.

Answer (score 3):

**Linux Ubuntu** instructions:

*Tested on Ubuntu 18.04:*

If you see this error *on Linux Ubuntu*:

> ```
> pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output
> ```

Then you need to install the `texlive-xetex` package like this:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

That solves it! Source where I learned this: [TEX: XeLatex under Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179811/168682).

In my particular case, I was trying to run this [`make_book.sh` script](https://gitlab.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/systemd-by-example/-/blob/master/make_book.sh) to generate `book.pdf`, so I needed to do all of the following:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pandoc
pip3 install MarkdownPP
sudo apt install texlive-xetex

cd path/to/repo
cd systemd-by-example
./make_book.sh
# You'll now have "book.pdf" inside directory "systemd-by-example"!
```

### References

1. https://github.com/jreese/markdown-pp - instructions to install MarkdownPP
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179811/168682 - instructions to install `texlive-xetex`

### See also

1. My answer on [Ask Ubuntu: How can I convert a .tex file to a PDF via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473017/327339) - **"Install `texlive` and all the extras: how to convert a .tex file to a PDF (TeX to PDF, and [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) to PDF)"**

Comment: That should be the top answer.